# what does pause track mean in play console

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I have uploaded an app in open testing (Release type) to let people use my app but without giving reviews to my app. Everything works well, many people used my app and really like it. So now I decided to release it in production (available for the world). I did that as well. But I want to remove the open testing app. So I saw an option Pause track in-play console (play.google.com). I have already made mistakes that took me days to re-correct them. So now I don't want any risks. Do the pause track button will remove the open testing or the production also.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See there are Four types of releases on play console for android developers;

**1. Internal testing -** It means you wanna share your app among the decided members. It means you have to put their Gmail into the testers list. This is usually for employees.

**2. Alpha testing -** Same as internal testing, but this time you can send your app to your friends, families or on your smartphones.

**3. Beta testing -** This is a serious matter, this is public testing. But people cannot give reviews to your app. You can also limit how many users can install the app.

**4. Production -** This is the last release, now everybody can install your app, can give reviews, can report to google play if something bad is there. One more thing, now your app appears in play store search listing.

So pause track means pausing that type of release. If you pause beta testing then the beta version will be removed from play store (actually hidden). Each release has its own pause button in their own page. Like you can see above.

Comment: What happens if you have both Beta testing and Production active, and then you go and pause Beta? What happens with the users initially enrolled in the Beta program, will they keep their apps in Production mode? Or will they be kicked off somehow?

Comment: Users will switch to production's latest version when they update the app. No one will be kicked out. You will not lose any user but they are able to give ratings to your app now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Worth to mention that production has no pause track only unpublish/publish if you want to remove the app.

Comment: Yes, because production is meant to be publishing the app, If you pause production means it is not visible to users which means, indirectly unpublished. Same options we have when we create blogs like draft, publish, unpublish. The term is different but the meaning is same.

Comment: Thanks very much for clearing this up @Vijay. I think the explaination "Users will switch to production's latest version when they update the app." would fit great behind the question mark button in Google Play Console.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer @Vijay. Also when we pause track the production release is reviewing again. I have realized now.

Comment: How to pause production track, there is no option to pause? Or How to remove from production completely and be in testing track only?

Comment: @SwaminathBera On the left menu, go to "Setup" > "Advanced settings."
In the "App Availability" section, click "Unpublish" to remove the app from the store.

Comment: @Vijay Yes, this removes the app from play store, but you cannot run closed or open track in this case too.

Comment: Yes For production, it is correct. The users that have downloaded the app, they will be able to use it. So You should have a functionality to block user from using the app. You can show an alert like 'Server Down, we are working on it'. I have used it in many application where I can block one or all users. It is important because sometimes there are bugs that can cause harm to database.

Comment: Another big difference not yet mentioned here is that you can publish an update instantly in the Internal track only. For all others you have to go through Google Review which can take days. Solely for this reason I use Internal & Production tracks only. I’m not sure why you think Internal for Employees, I use internal for testing with my team (practically friends and volunteers who agreed to be testers) just because I can roll out a new version instantly.

Comment: @MikeKeskinov Very good point, I will update the answer. Thanks 